# Selecting the same column multiple times as unioned column with only 1 select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a user defined function which returns a table in SQL Server, I need to run this over an entire table without using a cursor. I've tried to use union, but it requires multiple select statements. I've also tried to use unpivot but the column name is repeated so I can't combine the tables as one. Please let me know if there is something similar to my needs without using a cursor.

```
SELECT *
FROM UNION (
    SELECT dbo.calculatedates(value1fromtable1, value2fromtable1, value3...)
    from table1
)
```

Note: CalculateDates

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for `apply`?

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1 t1 CROSS APPLY
     dbo.calculatedates(t1.value1fromtable1, t1.value2fromtable1, t1.value3...) cd;
```

Comment: Thank you this was exactly what I was looking for.